# Is it faster to convert an array or list to a hashmap/dictionary and operate on it?

Tags: arrays, list, dictionary, data-structures, hashmap

I know this sounds very generic, but my understanding is that for the majority of coding problems hashmaps/dictionaries are the best (performance-wise) data structures. There are multiple situations where we are given an array or a list to manipulate (find, add, remove, etc.). Is it safe to say that for the majority of cases it is best to convert that array's indexes to hashmap/dictionary keys and values to values, and operate on this new hashmap/dictionary instead?

Comment: What about the various heaps, priority queues, etc.? All data structures have some targeted purpose and those are the situations when you typically use them. So no, I would not say that to be the case.

Answer (score 3):

You won't have any performance gains from converting an integer-indexed array to an integer-keyed map.

Accessing an element by index in an array is *always* an O(1) operation, whereas accessing an element in a hash table can be O(1) or O(log n) depending on the implementation (or in the worst case: O(n) if all the keys collide), but it'll certainly have an additional overhead compared to the array (calculating the hash, finding the right element in case of a collision, etc.)

It only makes sense to use a dictionary when the keys are not integers, or for representing very sparse integer-indexed arrays where only a few indexes are populated with elements.

Answer (score 0):

This question is way too broad. It depends on the actual goals you want to achieve. Lists and maps are around since ages and that has its reasons. E.g. a list allows ordering and also can contain the same item more than one time.

Answer (score 0):

Your question cannot be answered as this is a case-by-case answer. There are plenty of data structures and most of them are more performant than the others in really specific cases. This is because they all have trade offs.
Depending on how the purpose and what operations are executed the most, in some cases the hashmap could be more performant than the array and in some others, it would be the array.

For example you said "add" and "remove", but if you always add and remove at the end of your array, an array would be more performant.